# Maven Redundant Builds

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I have a multi module maven project where in there are 4 modules.

A
B
C
D (D depends on A, B, C)

All these modules have common dependencies like spring-data-mongodb etc.

When I do a clean install, I expect that all the above common dependencies are bundled into D but maven is bundling it into A, B, C as well and the D's jar file size is huge.

Is there a way to have maven put all the above common dependencies i.e. spring-data-mongodb etc. in one place and have all of A, B, C and D use that from inside the jar?

Thank you.

The parent pom is below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.betcade</groupId>
    <artifactId>betcade-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.21</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>com.betcade.core.AppLauncher</start-class>
    </properties>

    <name>betcade-core</name>
    <description>An aggregator project for a set of betcade core service related repositories</description>

    <modules>
        <module>A</module>
        <module>B</module>
        <module>C</module>
        <module>D</module>        

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring Boot Dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot Dependencies -->

        <!-- Apache Commons Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache Commons Dependencies -->

        <!-- Twilio SMS Gateway Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>twilio-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Twilio SMS Gateway Dependency -->

        <!-- Mandrill Mail API Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mandrillapp.wrapper.lutung</groupId>
            <artifactId>lutung</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mandrill Mail API Dependency -->

        <!-- MailGun API Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sargue</groupId>
            <artifactId>mailgun</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MailGun API Dependency -->

        <!-- Spring AWS Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-context</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- AWS Dependencies -->

        <!-- Joda Time Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Joda Time Dependency -->

        <!-- Quartz Scheduler Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Quartz Scheduler Dependency -->

        <!-- JSP Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSP Dependency -->

        <!-- XML Parsing Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.simpleframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>simple-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- XML Parsing Dependencies -->

        <!-- Apache POI Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.14-beta1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.14-beta1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache POI Dependencies -->

        <!-- DynamicReports Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.dynamicreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>dynamicreports-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- DynamicReports Dependencies -->

        <!-- JWT Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JWT Dependencies -->

        <!-- Timezone Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
            <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
            <version>57.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Timezone Dependencies -->        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

PS: This is a Spring boot project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with my configuration of the Sprint boot plugin (being added in the parent pom) which was bundling all the dependent jars into all the modules of the project.

Once I moved the build spring boot plugin to the appropriate module, maven put all the dependent jars into one place and things were fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your dependencies are bundled in each artifact because you've specified them in `<dependencies/>` of root POM. This list should contain only dependencies that are 100% needed for all of your modules. Good practice is to first define each of your project dependency with version in `<dependencyManagement/>` section of root POM, then specify only necessary dependencies in `<dependencies/>` section of each module POM.

Comment: Also you want to only have the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` in the file that is your actual application (project D) and not all projects as that will bundle everything in each jar.

Comment: frezykryger and M. Deinum : thank you for the suggestions. I was able to resolve the issue and have posted my answer below.